# How to make the AntiforgeryToken As Secure in ASP.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently I have a requirement that to make the Antiforgerytoken which is getting created by ASP.net MVC to make it secure

Basically Anti forgery token is a cookie in browser with name _RequestVerificationToken , want to make this as secure

I Already  tried

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <identity impersonate="false" />
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0" />
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" httpOnlyCookies="true"/>
```

But its not making the token as secure and httpOnly

if any one can help here , please

made the whole site hosted on Https too

Comment: Have you got the site hosted on https?

Comment: yes , i made it on https

Comment: Why do you want to make AntiforgeryToken as secure? What do you mean by that?

Comment: AntiforgeryToken basically a cookie , with name _RequestVerificationToken , we have to make this cookie as secure cookie in browser

Comment: If security is an issue, purchase a higher-class SSL certificate. Antiforgerytoken is already encrypted. Think of the cookie as a public key, it doesn't necessarily matter if someone sees/gets it. There is a hidden form field that is created, and used to decrypt the cookie when you use @Html.AntiForgeryToken(). It is already secure. Your boss doesn't seem to understand anti-forgery tokens if he thinks encrypting the cookie will help.

Comment: Thanks @Aaron , i got my answer form your comment .

Answer (score 3):

For when you are getting your chops busted by a security manager who has a vendor report saying that this cookie is not secure, try adding this to Startup.cs ConfigureServices

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.FormFieldName = "AntiforgeryFieldname";
    options.HeaderName = "X-CSRF-TOKEN-HEADERNAME";
    options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = false;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
});
```

[image: Chrome screenshot]
Refs
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1 &
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookiesecurepolicy?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score -2):

The anti-forgery token can be used to help protect your application against cross-site request forgery. To use this feature, all you need to do is add the following HTML helper to your form so it is submitted as part of the form post.

It used to product your form not entire mvc application.

For example if you want to secure your form.

View:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
      @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
      @Html.TextBox("Name")
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost] 
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()] 
public ActionResult PostMethod(FormCollection collection) 
{
   //Logic
}
```

Comment: I know How to implement Anti forgery token , but basically AntiforgeryToken is a cookie and want to make it secure in browser side

Comment: can you encrpyt the token ?